# Is is possible to setup internal exchange to send messages to the queue, if it's exist?

Tags: java, python, queue, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a situation, where I have a RabbitMQ cluster. I have multiple producers, which produce different data. I want each producer to setup a temporary queue based on parameters, and remove the queue if it's empty.

For example producers A and B:

```
A ----- tmp_a_queue

B ----- tnp_b_queue
```

I want to do this to scale throughput of the system. Next I want my consumer to create a single queue when it is able to consume, and grab messages from both queues.

For example adding consumer C to above template:

```
                          _______________________
A ----- tmp_a_queue\     |                       |
                     ====| SOME MAGIC GOES HERE  |-----tmp_c_queue C
B ----- tnp_b_queue/     |_______________________|
```

I know how to create `A`,`B` and `C`.

**Question:**

Is is it possible to setup some kind of `internal-exchange` in such a way that it would grab messages from all of the `tmp_queues` on the left (Note they come and go dynamically) and send them to the consumer queue (on the right), only if consumer is available?

Comment: I would think that each dynamically created queue would need a dynamically instantiated forwarder process responsible for forwarding on it's messages.  I suppose you could add a "check in" queue that each dynamic queue posts to so your "MAGIC" process know where to look when a new queue appears

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this as well. Do you know if internal excahnges might help me somehow?

Comment: That's not how I understand exchanges to work (though I'm intentionally avoiding posting any of this as an answer because I'm not that knowledgeable about message queues (just getting into them) so as to not discourage more knowledgeable people from looking at this question.  [Exchanges seem to work](http://rubyamqp.info/articles/working_with_exchanges/#using_the_publisher_confirms_extension_to_amqp_091) on the idea that you can take one message and distribute it to multiple queues (based on binding or topic), here you are trying for the reverse which sounds like just another queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Shovel](http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) plugin if you want the exchange to "consume" the messages. Queues subscribe to exchanges (bind to them), and not otherwise.

Or them you can have a **topic** exchange. Bind the tmp_queue_c with * and the others with their respective binding keys. But in this scenario, the other queues will still have their messages (they will not be consumed, unless somebody consumes them other than the exchange).

EDIT: I also have [found this link](http://www.rabbitmq.com/e2e.html) on exchange-to-exchange bindings that may prove useful in your case. In that scenario, you would have your normal exchange publishing to `tmp_a_queue` and `tmp_b_queue` but another exchange `magic` bound to the same exchange your 2 first queues are bound to. Then you bind `tmp_c_queue` to `magic` exchange and you'll achieve the desired behavior.